# How can I reference the element that contains the event from the function called?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, yui

From inside of the `fireAlert()` function, how can I reference the element that called it, without having to pass `this` as an argument through the link?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

//function
function fireAlert(){
    alert();
}

</script>

<a href="javascript:;" onclick="fireAlert();">Fire</a>
```

Comment: I am using YUI. So far, none of the answers have worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are easier ways of doing this with [jQuery](http://jquery.com),but this is how it's done without it:

**UPDATE:** Please try the following HTML/Javascript code. Notice how I am attaching the onclick event inside of window.onload instead of specifying it as an attribute at the element.

For this example, I'm attaching the event to all anchor tags in the page, but you could replace `getElementsByTagName` with `getElementById` for a specific one.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script language="javascript">
        function fireAlert(e)
        {
            var whoCalled = e ? e.target : event.srcElement;

            alert(whoCalled.innerHTML);
        }
        window.onload=function()
        {
            var allHrefs = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
            for(i=0;i<allHrefs.length;i++)
            {
                allHrefs[i].onclick=fireAlert;
            }
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#">Hello #1</a>
        <a href="#">Hello #2</a>
        <a href="#">Hello #3</a>
        <a href="#">Hello #4</a>        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Isn't srcElement specific to IE only?

Comment: This solution worked neither in FF or IE7. "window.event is undefined". Using Firebug, I cannot find any object named event. I am able to find the onclick event with it's associated element in the stack (in Firebug), but I don't know how to reference that in the code.

Comment: @Jamis - I updated my original post with new code that I tested in FF, IE7 and Chrome.

Comment: @Jose - Thanks. I am aware that you can reference e as the event inside the function if you add the event unobtrusively (one way would be to use YUI's Event.addeventlistener() function). Is there any way you can reference event e while using an inline event i.e. '<a onclick="fire()" href="">' ?

Comment: I researched this very thoroughly and that does not work in FF because it doesn't have the event object.

Comment: You can reference the event when using an inline event by passing the event object to the function. See http://quirksmode.org/js/events_access.html#link6 for an example.

Comment: That's exactly what Jamis does not want. He wants the onclick() to be specified without parameters as an attribute of the element. This works in IE, but not FF. In FF, it works in my example.

Comment: Thanks for the hard work guys. I'll just have to accept that this is not possible for now :).

Answer (score 0):

As Jose said, it would be easy with jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("a").click(function()
    {
        // this == the clicked element
    });
});
```

Comment: I am using YUI. So if there was an easy way to do this with YUI, that'd work too.